# Selecting unique dates depending on a unique ID in R

Tags: r, date, unique, distinct

My data has two columns:

```
id <-c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3)
dates <-c("1/1/2001", "2/1/2001", "2/1/2001", "3/1/2001", "4/1/2001", "4/1/2001", "5/1/2001")
example<-data.frame(id, dates)
```

I want to find the unique/distinct id and then find all unique dates for that id in the dates column. In the example, I would have 3 unique IDs and for each id a different number of unique dates.

Comment: `unique(example)`

Comment: Please go through the duplicated link and let us know if you have an expected output different from that. It counts the number of unique id's per group.

Comment: I searched inefficiently, I guess. Thank you